# Setting up Continues Integration with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to setup Continues Integration for my DEV box.

Here is what I did in Visual Studio Team Services

1. Setup Repository for test SharePoint Project
2. Setup continues build(with default hosted agent)
3. Setup Release for my DEV box with one test power shell script which has only one below statement(with default hosted agent)

   Write-Output "this is test deployment"

Step 1 and 2 works well but in Step 3 it fails on executing powershell script and gives me below error.

*System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Connecting to remote server  failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Connecting to remote server  failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.*

Edit: 4-Aug-2016
Updating based on comments from Preet Singh

Initially I tried to setup Default agent to do build and release but then I installed agent on my box and then tried but got the same error.

If I looked at log it failed on below step.

Deployment started for machine: 'machinename:port'

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy.

Comment: I am trying to deploy on my Development Environment(on premise).

Comment: Ok so the error is quite clear. The Visual studio team services cannot access your local or on premises Dev env machine.

Comment: I also installed the agent on my machine but that gave me the same error.

Comment: Do you have a proxy on your network? maybe this is not set up properly for the service account you're trying to use to run the agent.

Comment: Silly me... When I ran "winrm quickconfig" command it prompted me with "Make this changes [y/n]?" and I pressed enter assuming enter = y and I was wrong. After some troubleshooting I ran the same command and then pressed "y+enter" and it worked.